# Yii2, не работает связь hasOne

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2

Есть проект на Yii2, веб-сервер настроен правильно (другие проекты аналогичные работают без проблем)

Есть две модели Stud и Klass В первой модели делаю связь

```
public function getKlas()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Klass::className(), ['id' => 'klass']);
}

public function getKlass1()
{
    return $this->klas->klass2;
}
```

соответственно есть id у модели Klass и поле klass в модели Stud, но получаю:

```
 PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
 Trying to get property of non-object
```

В чём может быть проблема? Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вы посмотрели что в `$this->klas`.
Знания о реализованнии связей беру из Laravel, но все же. Мне кажется в `$this->klas` null - от сюда и ошибка.

Comment: да, вы правы, ошибка оказалось в этом.